# The thread is killed when using Photopicker to pick a video and then playing it

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to let users pick their videos from their photo library and playing it in app. I follow the guide as below: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-import-videos-using-photospicker. And I modify the codes a little to save every video to an unique URL.

But when a video is picked, the app always is frozen and the thread is killed. It seems that FileManager can't handle large files, like video file. Could anyone give an advice about it?

My codes is as following:

```
import SwiftUI

***struct Movie: Transferable {
    let url: URL
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
            SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
        } importing: { received in
            let id = UUID().uuidString
            let copy1 = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: id)
            let copy = copy1.appending(path: "movie.mov")
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copy.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copy)
            }
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
            return Self.init(url: copy)
        }
    }
}***

 ***PhotosPicker(
                            selection: $selectedItems,
                            maxSelectionCount: 3,
                            matching:.any(of:[.videos]),
                            photoLibrary: .shared()
                        ){
                            Image("videos")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                .padding(.trailing, 18)
                        }
                        .onChange(of:selectedItems){oldValue, newValue in
                            Task {
                                for value in newValue {
                                    do {
                                        loadState = .loading
                                        
                                        if let movie = try await value.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                                            loadState = .loaded(movie)
                                            noteVideoUrls.append(movie.url)
                                        } else {
                                            loadState = .failed
                                        }
                                    } catch {
                                        loadState = .failed
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }***
                        
***ForEach(noteVideoUrls, id: \.self){url in
                                    ZStack(alignment:.topTrailing){
                                        switch loadState {
                                                    case .loading:
                                                        ProgressView()
                                                    case .loaded:
                                                        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                                                            .scaledToFit()
                                                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                                                    case .failed:
                                                        Text("Import failed")
                                                    }***
```

Comment: Have you tried running this logic on a different thread(background)?

Comment: use `task(id:)` instead of `onChange` Apple seems to be canceling those floating tasks lately